# AngularJS: How to only show items in json file that have a certain value(s) based on a nested array of a variable

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-show

Please note:  This is my first angular application so I apologize if I'm asking a wrong or silly question.

I'm using ng-repeat to list data items present in a json file.  I want to be able to list only the data (ng-show) necessary for different partials of a SPA. The site is a personal website for family recipes.  Upon a button click I want to be able to only list dessert foods, etc. I already have this working, but I'm using multiple json files with duplicated data to accomplish this (dirty data?).  The goal is to have only one json file for the whole site.

Here is an example of one variable or "dish" in the data set:

```
{
    "name": "Pecan Pie",
    "shortname": "pecan-pie",
    "type": [
        "dessert",
        "holidaydish"
    ],
    "contributor": "Mark",
    "totalt": "1h 5m",
    "ingredients": "1 cup light brown sugar",
    "steps": "Preheat oven to 400 degrees.",
},
```

I'm trying to show data based on the nested array for the value: "type"

HTML in partials calling each variable in the json file:

(This is where I have been failing to use ng-show to show only the variables or "dishes" that have dessert / etc. in the nested type array)

```
<li class="dishlistli" ng-repeat="item in dish | filter: query | orderBy: dishOrder:direction">
  <a href="#/allcards/{{dish.indexOf(item)}}">
    <div>
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2></div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Ex Controller for a partial:

```
dishControllers.controller('AllcardsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/all.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.IsVisible = false;
    $scope.ShowHide = function() {
      $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
    }

    $scope.dish = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

    if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
      $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) - 1;
    } else {
      $scope.prevItem = $scope.dish.length - 1;
    }

    if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.dish.length - 1) {
      $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) + 1;
    } else {
      $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Any time and help with this is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I'm missing any necessary information.

The working version of the app (using multiple json files) is at:  http://clarkecookbook.com/#/all

I can always continue to use the multiple json files, but I would like to know how to do this right.

Comment: you can filter the ng-repeat with the `filter` property even in nested

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, not yet.  I just don't know enough about Angular to create my own custom filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li class="dishlistli" ng-repeat="item in dish | filter: query | orderBy: dishOrder:direction" ng-if="showDelete(item.type)">
```

Using the above ng-if directive along with adding the below function to the controller enabled me to only display the desired data items based on the type variable.

```
$scope.showDelete = function(itemType){
    var testType = "drink";

    if(testType.indexOf(itemType) > -1){ //test the Type
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo ther : http://plnkr.co/edit/qLwfnkOdxjoJ5pjPcZYQ?p=preview

try this in the view :

```
<input ng-model="query"/>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="e in list | filter: {type: query}">
    {{e.name}}  (type: {{e.type}})
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This confused me a bit.  Doesn't this call the type variable with an e in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make more complex filters then you could create a function into which you pass the object of the ng-repeat. Check the type values of the object within the function against the query object and then return true if found or false otherwise.

You can use one json file. You just need to change the data model to reflect the JSON file's structure. Also, it's considered best practice to use ng-href instead of href in angular because you can't guarantee that angular will have replaced the bracketed text before it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the ng-href tip.  I think I need to learn a little more angular before I can get this to work how I want it to.